# Can't swap between two bootable drives

Tags: debian, boot, raid1

I'm attempting to setup a 2-drive (sda, sdb) RAID 1 in my PC, using Raider to convert from my old single drive (sda) system to the new RAID 1.

From sda, on sdb I ran:

```
# raider -R1 
# raider --run
```

and it finished ok setting up the empty drive into the RAID array and copied all data. Now I have to swap the disks, but I can't make my PC boot from sdb, it always boot from sda.

I've tried to modify the BIOS boot settings but nothing changed, I can only choose HD as boot device and change mount order, but not boot order between them.

I'm using Debian Squeeze and Grub as boot loader.

**EDITED**

Motherboard: ASROCK N68C-S UCC

HD: 2x 1Tb WD SATA2

Comment: Does your server not have hot swap drive bays?  Just pull the drives and put them back in in the opposite order.  What kind of server is it?

Comment: I'm sorry, It's a regular PC, I use it as a server at home, sorry. I'll edit & change it.

Comment: Can you please provide your grub.conf file? It's typically under /etc or /boot.

Comment: /boot/grub/grub.cfg? it's an autogenerated file, it think it's not what you need, isn't it? I've been looking for the clasical menu.lst but I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, to boot from second drive, in GRUB's command line:

> ```
> set root=(hd1)
> chainloader +1
> ```